# i am willing to design the recycler view but how do i see what my recycler view element looks?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

How can I visualize what my recycler view elements look like? my question is when we set up the recyclerView, it's a very difficult task. How should I preview my recycler view element in the layout design?

[image]

I want to visualize the recycler view element so that design it

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recylerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView12"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_title"
    tools:itemCount="4"/>
```

Here `tools:listitem` for preview of item and `tools:itemCount` for number of preview items

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add a listview element in the recycler view, kindly add this linear layout,listItem, and orientation in the recycler view so that you can design it.

```
  tools:listitem="@layout/viewholder_category"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

[image]